# How do i match a username with password in c?

Tags: c

Iwant to write a login program. I want every username to match its specific password. For example, the username "Asma" should only be logged in with the password "Hello123" not with "Welcome".

But somehow when I enter every username and password from the string array, it says "Logged in successfully". How do I make every username to match its own password? Also, how do I ask for a valid input again when the username and password are both incorrect?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char username[10];
    char password[10];

    printf("Enter your username: ");
    scanf("%s", username);

    printf("Enter your password: ");
    scanf("%s", password);

    if(strcmp(username,"Asma") == 0 || strcmp(username,"Iffat") == 0 || strcmp(username,"Kamal") == 0 ){
    if(strcmp(password,"Hello123") == 0 || strcmp(password,"Welcome") == 0  || strcmp(password,"fr1324") == 0 ){

        printf("Logged In Successfully");   

        }else{
    printf("Incorrect username or password, please try again! ");
}

}else{

printf("Incorrect username or password, please try again! ");    
}
```

Comment: There is no connection between any username and password in your code, so you should start by creating that (e.g.: via a `struct` that hold the username and password that belong together)

Comment: All you have there are a bunch of OR logical operators `||`.  If you want a correlation between a user name and their password, there's gotta be an AND `&&` in there somewhere.

Comment: Please throw your C learning book out of the window if it tells you to use scanf to read strings. It's highly dangerous. What if my username or password is longer than 9 characters? (And the should be longer.)

Comment: You allow any combination between usernames and passwords. Check them in pairs: `if ( ( strcmp( username, "user1" ) == 0 && strcmp( password, "pwd1" ) == 0 ) || ( strcmp( username, "user2" ) == 0 && strcmp( password, "pwd2" ) == 0 ) ...`

Comment: With the `strings` command I can find all passwords on your system.  Storing passwords is inherently insecure.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to match a username with a password, you should use `&&` to make sure both checks succeed:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char username[10];
    char password[10];

    printf("Enter your username: ");
    scanf("%s", username);

    printf("Enter your password: ");
    scanf("%s", password);

    if (strcmp(username, "Asma") == 0 && strcmp(password, "Hello123") == 0
        || strcmp(username, "Iffat") == 0 && strcmp(password, "Welcome") == 0
        || strcmp(username, "Kamal") == 0 && strcmp(password, "fr1324") == 0) {
            printf("Logged In Successfully");
    } else {
        printf("Incorrect username or password, please try again! ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Be aware that this (though working) solution is not the way this should be done. You should have an array of structs connecting usernames to their coresponding passwords. Imagine you have 100 users and not just 3, your code would be a big mess.

Answer (score 3):

> How do I make every username to match its own password?

The way your code is currently written, all you're doing is making sure they match *any* username and *any* password - you're not matching a specific password to a specific username.

And while checking each name and password explicitly is okay as a first attempt, it's not going to scale - this will quickly get unmanageable beyond 5 usernames or so.  It might be better for you to create a lookup table of names and passwords using a `struct` type:

```
struct usertable {
  char *name;
  char *pass;
};

...

struct usertable users[] = { // array size is taken from the number of initializers
  {"Asma", "Hello123"},
  {"Iffat", "Welcome"},
  {"Kamal", "fr1234"},
  ...                        // any other entries
  {NULL, NULL}               // explicitly mark the last entry in the table
};
```

and then after you enter your username and password, you cycle through the table like so:

```
/**
 * Cycle through all the entries in users until logged_in is true
 * or we hit the end of the table.  
 */
int logged_in = 0;
for ( size_t i = 0; users[i].name != NULL && !logged_in; i++ )
{
    /**
     * Perform a logical AND against the results of strcmp for both
     * the username and password, assign the result (0 or 1) to logged_in.
     */
  logged_in = (strcmp( username, users[i].name ) == 0 &&
               strcmp( password, users[i].pass ) == 0 );
}

if ( !logged_in )
  printf( "Username or password not found, try again\n" );
```

> Also, how do I ask for a valid input again when the username and password are both incorrect?

Put all of the above in a loop that only exits when you match the password or when you signal `EOF` on input (using Ctrl-D or Ctrl-Z, depending on your system):

```
int logged_in = 0;

/**
 * Loop until the logged_in flag is true or we see a break statement
 */
while ( !logged_in ) 
{
  printf( "Enter username: " );         // scanf is *not* the right tool for
  if ( scanf( "%s", username ) == EOF ) // this, but we'll keep it in place
    break; // exit while loop           // because otherwise this example
                                        // would be three times as big
  printf( "Enter password: " );         // and I don't to bury the main point
  if ( scanf( "%s", password ) == EOF ) // of the exercise.
    break; // exit while loop

  for( size_t i = 0; users[i].name != NULL && !logged_in; i++ )
  {
    logged_in = (strcmp( users[i].name, username ) == 0 && 
                 strcmp( users[i].pass, password ) == 0 );
  }

  if ( !logged_in )
  {
    fprintf( stderr, "Username or password not found, try again.\n" );
    fprintf( stderr, "Type Ctrl-Z to quit.\n" );
  }
}

/**
 * If logged_in is still 0 at this point, that means the user entered
 * Ctrl-Z to quit, and we exit the program.
 */
if ( !logged_in )
{
  fprintf( stderr, "Exiting...\n" );
  exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );              // "Normal" exit
}

printf( "Logged in successfully\n" );
```

Comment: That's quite difficult for me as I'm an absolute beginner. Appreciate your detailed answer though.